# Unexpected syntax error produced by running generated YACC parser

Tags: c, bison, yacc

For example I have the code

```
%nonassoc lower
%nonassoc ELSE

if_stmt: IF '(' expr ')' statement   %prec lower
         {
            /*some code*/
         }
       | IF '(' expr ')' statement ELSE statement
         {
            /*some code*/
         }
       ;
```

With the rules and code (which don't do much) I now  get " **elsesyntax** **error** " when I test an IF-ELSE statement. If it is only an IF statement it works fine.

I thought that I should pass something in the 2nd action in order for it to work but I'm not sure what.

If possible, I would like not to separate the 2 actions.

EDIT:  So here is the grammar as asked, and the precedence:
EDIT2 : implemented my grammar rules. compound_stmt and local_declarations are comments cause i don't yet know what to do with them.

```
%nonassoc islowerthanelse
%nonassoc ELSE

%%

%token <intVal> NUM WHILE PRINT IF ELSE INT 

program            :    declaration_list statement_list       
                         {
                         printf("/0\n");

                         }
                         ;                                    

declaration_list   :    declaration_list declaration          
                          {
                            printf("/1\n");
                            $$ = make_node(DeclSeq, NULL, $1, $2, NULL, NULL);
                          }
                         |declaration 
                         {
                            printf("/2\n");
                            $$ = $1;
                         }                        
                         ;

declaration        :    type_specifier ID ';'                  
                          {
                            printf("/3\n");
                            $$ = make_node(Decl, p3, $1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                           }

type_specifier     :    INT                                   
                          {
                            printf("/5\n");
                            $$ = make_node(INT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

                          }
                         ;

statement_list     :    statement_list statement              
                         {
                           printf("/6\n");
                           $$ = make_node(StmtSeq, NULL, $1, $2, NULL, NULL);
                         }
                         |/* EMPTY */
                          {
                            printf("/7\n");
                            $$ = make_node(astEmptyStmtSeq, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

                          }
                         ;

statement          :    expression_stmt                       
                          {
                            printf("/8\n");
                            $$ = $1;
                          }
                         /*|compound_stmt                       
                          {
                            $$ = $1;
                          }*/
                         |selection_stmt                      
                          {
                            $$ = $1;
                          }
                         |iteration_stmt                      
                          {
                            $$ = $1;
                          }
                         |print_stmt                          
                          {
                            printf("/12\n");
                            $$ = $1;
                          }
                         ;

/*compound_stmt      :    '{' local_declarations statement_list '}' 
                         ;

local_declarations :    local_declarations declaration
                         |/* EMPTY *\
                         ;*/

expression_stmt    :    expression ';'                       
                          {
                            printf("/15\n");
                            $$ = make_node(ExprStmt, NULL, $1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                          }                 
                         |/* EMPTY */ ';'
                          {
                            printf("/16\n");
                            $$ = make_node(EmptyExprStmt, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                          }
                         ;

selection_stmt     :    IF '(' expression ')' statement      %prec islowerthanelse      
                          { printf("/256\n");
                            $$ = make_node(IfStmt, NULL, $3, $5, NULL, NULL);

                          }      
                         |IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement 
                          {printf("/257\n");
                            $$ = make_node(IfElseStmt, NULL, $3, $5, $7, NULL);
                          }                    
                         ;

iteration_stmt     :    WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
                          {
                            $$ = make_node(astWhileStmt, NULL, $3, $5, NULL, NULL);
                          }
                          ;
```

Comment: Diagnosing yacc/bison grammar problems is almost impossible without seeing the full grammar.  You need to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get useful help.

Comment: I think your 'grammar and precedence' section shows what you're supposed to implement, whereas the problem is in what you do implement.  We probably need to see a minimal version of your Yacc grammar that reproduces the problem (see [MCVE]).  The problem occurs at run-time, I believe.  That is, your grammar compiles and the program links, but you get an unwanted error when you execute it on an IF / ELSE statement — is that correct?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i am not linking something,is that wrong?
i flex the lexer,yacc the parser,gcc the .c files and with the .exe produced i put some code for testing.

Comment: The process of creating the `.exe` from the object files (or, at least, the C source from Flex and Yacc/Bison) is the 'linking' process I referred to.  Please read the information on creating an MCVE.  One of the key parts of an MCVE is the input that you give it, with the output you get and the output you expect.  Another key part is usually sufficient code that we can compile and run the test.  It's harder with a lexer; maybe you can write a dummy that simply returns the correct sequence of tokens and value to generate the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess from the fragment show -- your `%prec lower` actually has a higher precedence that the `ELSE` token, so when seeing an `ELSE` it will reduce the first rule, and then get a syntax error as it can't do anything with the `ELSE` after the reduction.

However, actually answering this question would require seeing the full grammar.

---

I added the following to your grammar to make an MVCE:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#define make_node(...)  0
%}

%nonassoc islowerthanelse
%nonassoc ELSE

%token NUM WHILE PRINT IF INT ID
%token expression print_stmt

%%
```

:

```
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
int main() { return yyparse(); }
int yywrap() { return 1; }
void yyerror(const char *msg) { printf("%s\n", msg); }
```

Along with a trivial lexer:

```
%%
"while" return WHILE;
"print" return PRINT;
"if" return IF;
"else" return ELSE;
"int" return INT;
"expression" return expression;
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* return ID;
[0-9]* return NUM;
[ \t\n] ;
. return *yytext;
```

and an input file like:

```
int A;
if (expression) expression; else expression;
```

and it appears to work just fine...

```
$ a.out <input.txt/5
/3
/2
/7
/15
/8
/15
/8
/257
/6
/0
```

Comment: If I add the necessary missing stuff to actually compile and run your grammar (simple lexer/main/missing declarations) it parses an if/else just fine.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post some example code?I am still experiencing the same problem with an if-else statement.I am a little bit pressured here,that's why i can't provide a minimal example myself.

Answer (score 0):

Actions are independent of each other; there is no"fall-through". If you want to refactor common code between two actions, put it into a function which can be called from the actions.

However, that should have nothing to do with the syntax error you are seeing. Actions do not affect the parse; if the parser reports a syntax error, it will do so without running any action (since the error reflects the impossibility of finding an appropriate production).

Comment: so,since the production is there,how can i make it see it?

Comment: @codenewbie: i'm sure that bison sees the production :) There is some problem in your grammar, but we'd need to see more than one rule to tell what it is. [mcve]

Comment: i edited my question with some of my grammar rules(in case you don't get noticed when i edit,don't know how it works)

Comment: @codeNewbie: i see that various comments include the link to [mcve] but it diesn't look like you read it. A minimal example is not an extract of your program: it is a short but complete program which shows the same problem.

Comment: (And, by the way, the part of the grammar you show does *not* show what you claim to be the problem, although I don't see how it can produce the output you claim to see, either. If you want to debug a bison grammar, you are *much* better off using the [built-in trace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Enabling-Traces.html#Enabling-Traces) than manually adding `printf` statements throughout your grammar, and not just because it is easier to turn off an on but because it traces all useful events.)